# Set StackPanel background to WP7 selected accent (theme) color

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, background-color, stackpanel

I am wondering if it is possible to set the background of my StackPanel to the Windows Phone 7 user selected accent (theme) color. I have heard that you are supposed to use styles so it can be used for all the StackPanels on the current xaml page. However I am a bit lost.

Example of my current static background color:

```
<StackPanel Width="400" Background="#FF1BA1E2" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" Tag="ABC">
       <TextBlock Text="ABC" FontSize="50" Margin="10" />
</StackPanel>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

PS: Just in case anyone is wondering the hexadecimal value "#FF1BA1E2" is the color of the default WP7 blue accent (theme).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the built in static resources to automatically get the theme color:

```
Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
```

Comment: I tried to use it but I got an exception while the app was loading that page.

<code>Attribute {StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle} value is out of range.</code>

Comment: @Spalatum what was hte exception?

Comment: @Spalatum Sorry, my mistake fixed the example. THat'll teach me to test things first, not rely on memory.

Comment: Is there a documentation where I can find the list of StaticResources available by default?

Answer (score 3):

i have encountered the same exception while trying this.
just try Apply Binding to the `Background` through Properties tab.
or hardcode this into the xaml file, to the stackpanel element

`Background="{Binding Source={StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}}"`

it solves the exception. :)

Comment: Very clever! For me, this was needed for a `Button` background.